# How to use FileManager correctly?

Tags: swift

I use

```
let url = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group....")?.appendingPathComponent("hello")
            let data = Data("289".utf8)
            try! data.write(to: url!)
            
            let url2 = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.co...")?.appendingPathComponent("mannschaft")
            let data2 = Data("114".utf8)
            try! data2.write(to: url2!)
```

to write some data on a file.

And later i use these two on different swift files :

```
let teamId: String = {
            let url = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.co....")?.appendingPathComponent("hello")
            let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url!)
            let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
            return string
            }()
```

and

```
let vergleichmannschaft: String = {
        let url = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.co...")?.appendingPathComponent("mannschaft")
        let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url!)
        let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
        return string
        }()
```

to read it. But the simulator chrashes and says: `Thread 1: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “mannschaft” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserIn`

"hello" works but not "mannschaft"

Answer (score 0):

You should never use `try!` unless you are sure that this will never fail. You need to make sure that the file exists on that location or return an emptyString. You should also make it a computed property. Make sure you have already created your file before fetching its contents. Btw you should add the `".txt"` pathExtension to your text file names:

```
var vergleichmannschaft: String {
    guard let url = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.co...")?.appendingPathComponent("mannschaft.txt") else {
        return ""
    }
    return (try? String(contentsOf: url,encoding: .utf8)) ?? ""        
}
```